# ssh-config multihop tunnel

Tags: ssh, putty, tunnel

I have an mysql Server on hostD.
I can access hostD through hostC,
hostC through hostB, hostB through hostA
and I access hostA using putty on my home device

```
home(windows)-->hostA-->hostB-->hostC--hostD(mySQL Server)
```

My goal is to access the server from my home device.

Another challenge is that I don't have any root access on A,B and C.
Now I've been experimenting with the '.ssh/config' file and this is what I got so far:

```
 Host BTunnel
  HostName hostB
  LocalForward 3306 localhost:3306

 Host CTunnel
  HostName hostC
  LocalForward 3306 localhost:3306

 Host DTunnel
  HostName hostD
  LocalForward 3306 localhost:3306
```

This way I can connect from Putty--> hostA and type in consecutively:

```
ssh BTunnel
ssh CTunnel
ssh DTunnel
```

To get a tunnel from A to D.
But I would like to have a solution, where I only type in 1 command from host A to get a Tunnel to D, maybe by chaining up the existing host aliases.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can just chaining the commands. You can do this even without any config files. Execute at hostA:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 hostB ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 hostC ssh -NL 3306:localhost:3306 hostD
```

If you have configs and public keys in place, you can do:

```
ssh BTunnel ssh CTunnel ssh -N DTunnel
```

(I would include the -N at the last command because I don't need shell access, just the forwarding.) You can make an alias for it in .bashrc (or similar):

```
alias mytunnel="ssh BTunnel ssh CTunnel ssh -N DTunnel"
```

you can start with mytunnel now.